# iPhone/iPad UIImage initWithContentsOfFile:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, memory-leaks, uiimage

I have written code that when you hit button, it opens new screen with image on it. On that new screen there is button that dismisses screen, and returns to main screen.  And it works fine if i do it like this (no leaks etc...):

```
img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Galaxy"];
ImageDisplay *display = [[ImageDisplay alloc] initWithImage:img];
```

But if i replace this line of code with something like this:

```
img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Minnesota" ofType:@"png"]];
ImageDisplay *display = [[ImageDisplay alloc] initWithImage:img];
[img release];
```

It acts as i have memory leak. Every time i open image screen, app takes more and more memory. But all deallocs are called, even [img retainCount] shows 1 before final release. Is there possibility that there is a bug here, because i cant find whats wrong?

EDIT:

Here is dealloc method for ImageDisplay, and this method gets called:

```
 -(void) dealloc {
     [img release];
     [super dealloc];
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `ImageDisplay *display` is retaining the image. As it should be. When you release that, it should release all its retained entities. In the code you've shown, you're not releasing it. The typical use would be to tell the containing view controller to display it modally or something (or push it onto a navigation controller) and release it, leaving its retain lifecycle in the hands of whatever view controller is now managing it. The difference is, in your first code sample, `*img` is autoreleased, and will release itself when appropriate, and in the second, it's not.

ARC would save your bacon here, and dramatically simplify your code.

Also you should google the term "static method", because you're working really hard to call static methods as instances of the class of objects, which is like going around your ass to get to your elbow.

ALSO, stop looking at `retainCount`. All sorts of things might retain your objects under the hood of the framework. Using retainCount as part of your debugging strategy is a one way ticket to confusionville.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since imageNamed: is a class method not an instance method, you use it like this:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pony.png"];
```

Your posted code using `initWithContentsOfFile` looks correct, so the leak must be somewhere in your ImageDisplay class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one instead, you dont need to allocate and release:

```
 [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)name]
```

Comment: is it better/faster than `initWithContentsOfFile`?

Comment: I have just tried it, it consumed much less memory than your way.